# Maximum of All Numbers Between All Numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

To analyze my data in excel, I'm trying to get the maximum of a set of data that is in between two times.

I have already tried MAXIFS multiple ways, but it never seems to work. I always get 0

```
=MAXIFS('All The Solar Data'!F:F,'All The Solar Data'!D:D,"<'MAX PROTON'!B2")
```

The goal is for a set of data between two dates to be searched and the maximum to be output.

Comment: Some sample data and your desired results would really help out here. Otherwise we have to reverse engineer your non-working formula to understand why it's non-working.

Comment: `"<'MAX PROTON'!B2"` should be `"<" & 'MAX PROTON'!B2`

Answer (score 0):

Syntax Error - "<'MAX PROTON'!B2" should be "<" & 'MAX PROTON'!B2

Thank you @Scott Craner